# Sending an NSTimer target message to a different class; extracting its userInfo parameter

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nstimer

I am using an NSTimer to send a message on an interval. Here is the code :

```
{
    // ....
    var params : [String] = []
    params.append(conversion)
    params.append(message)
    let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: date, interval: 60, target: self, selector: Selector("importTextMessage.sendMessage:"), userInfo: params, repeats: true)

    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    // ...
}


func sendMessage(params: [String]){ ...}
```

I have also tried changing to the Swift 2.2 syntax:

```
let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: date, interval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(importTextMessage.sendMessage(_:)), userInfo: params, repeats: true)
```

but that does not change anything.

From every other question posted about the "Unrecognized selector sent to instance", the response is "include a colon in the Selector so that it knows to grab arguments from UserInfo", but I have included that, and can't figure out what is wrong.

What to Note:

The parameters for the function and the parameters passed in through NSTimer userInfo DO match up. They are both arrays of strings.

If it means anything, the code is failing while sendMessage is being called. It does not actually make it to sendMessage.

I am getting an odd warning saying that "String literal is not a valid objective-c selector"

I tried changing my code for my sendMessage to take the Timer as an argument as 1 user suggested : `func sendMessage(timer: NSTimer){`but that still gives the same error.

Thank you for your help in advance, I do appreciate it.

EDIT: here is the function that runs the timer:     //Save all of the data
    @IBAction func saveText(sender: AnyObject) {
        var phone       : Double
        var active      : Int
        var frequency   : Double
        var message     : String
        var date        : NSDate

```
    phone = Double(currentNumber)!
    active = 1
    message = myTextView.text
    date = myDatePicker.date

    switch self.frequency.selectedRowInComponent(0) {
        case 0:
            frequency = 1
        case 1:
            frequency = 3
        case 2:
            frequency = 6
        case 3:
            frequency = 24
        case 4:
            frequency = 168
        case 5:
            frequency = 744
        default:
            frequency = 8760
    }

    importTextMessage.seedMessage(phone, active: active, frequency: frequency, message: message, date: date)

    print(date)
    let conversion : String = "+1" + String(Int(phone))


    //importTextMessage.sendMessage("Ryan", to: conversion, message: message)
    var params : [String] = []
    params.append(conversion)
    params.append(message)
    //importTextMessage.sendMessage(params)

    let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: date, interval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(importTextMessage.sendMessage(_:)), userInfo: params, repeats: true)
    //        
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

}
```

EDIT: Exact error mssg:

unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe6b915460
2016-07-25 13:26:09.092 Harass Your Kate[53524:9000621] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Harass_Your_Kate.AddMessageViewController sendMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe6b915460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API of NSTimer is such that the receiver (target function) must take one and only one parameter, of type NSTImer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

> The message to send to target when the timer fires.
>
> The selector should have the following signature: timerFireMethod:
>   (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument). The
>   timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the
>   following pattern:
>
> - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer

In Swift the signature *must* be

*edit: updated to match your code exactly*

*Note: Swift 2.2 syntax*

```
class TextMessageViewController: UIViewController {
    var importTextMessage: AddMessageViewController // init'd somehow

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...

        // Note how selector matches *the name of the class*
        // As I understand it now, the sendMessage method
        // is declared in the AddMessageViewController class,
        // and importTextMessage is the name of the instance of that class.
        // And we're in a different class now, TextMessageViewController,
        // so using `self` does not make sense here.
        let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: date, interval: 60, target: importTextMessage,
            selector: #selector(AddMessageViewController.sendMessage(_:)), userInfo: params, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }
}


class AddMessageViewController: UIViewController {
    // func must not be private
    func sendMessage(timer: NSTimer) {
       // And now for example
       print("params: \(timer.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

As far as your userInfo dictionary, that is a *property* of the timer object, not a parameter to the target function itself.

The **SECOND** mistake is that the selector syntax is failing to use the *name of the class as declared*, not the name of some instance variable that has a reference to that class instance. Include more context in your question so it'll get solved faster!

The **THIRD** mistake is that you're using the wrong class name. If you use `self`, then the class name in the selector *must match the name of the current class*. Since you really want the message *to go to a different class*, you must use *that* reference instead. See updated code.

I think you still don't fully grasp object references, and their types, and how they must match, and how `self` is just the reference to the contextual object.

Comment: Since this is correct, it probably shouldn't be downvoted, but I'm curious as to why.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but it does not help the code. I have the exact thing you and the other answerer has, but it does not change the error. It still says that Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13601f910'

Comment: If its Swift3 add underscore before the first parameter of your method

Comment: Please update your question to include the surrounding class, and the exact target function handling code. It can't be a private function.

Comment: I included an underscore and that doesn't change it still. Here is exactly what it looks like : let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: date, interval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(importTextMessage.sendMessage(_:)), userInfo: params, repeats: true)

Comment: Updated once more (I believe this is final) after troubleshooting from question's comments.

Comment: @BaseZen, I tried your solution, and it is still giving me the same error. I don't know where to go from here. If you can recommend any further steps, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Upload your entire project to GitHub or some public sharing area. You must have a few layers of mistakes.

Comment: Fixed what I have determined to be a 3rd problem. Please try.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. No one has ever spent this much time helping me, I can't begin to express how thankful I am. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

From [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:):

> The timer passes itself as the argument

so your timer expect other argument type, `NSTimer`. Try this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var params : [String] = []
    params.append(conversion)
    params.append(message)
    let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: date, interval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(sendMessage(_:)), userInfo: params, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

func sendMessage(sender: NSTimer) {
    print(sender.userInfo as? [String])
}
```

This code works fine in my standard view controller

Comment: When I implement that code, it doesn't change anything. Before sendMessage even executes, the error is thrown. When I go through the debugger, my params are correct : p params
([String]) $R0 = 2 values {
  [0] = "+1.....52"
  [1] = "Hey there,"
}

Comment: After exiting the function it gives the error. After stepping past NSRunLoop, it steps through some Assembly instructions and then throws the error. the error is NSInvalidArgumentException and unrecognized selector @Shadow Of

Comment: @Ryan I don't see any chance for errors for now. Please provide some more code. Error can be in `date` getter (replace it by `NSDate()`) or somwhere else

Comment: I included the full function on the save text button press. If that doesn't help, I can include anything you need. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan Is your class final or private? It might be a matter of your sentMessage method not being exposed to the Objective-C runtime. Try adding the `@objc` decorator to the method definition.

Comment: I would just like to be clear - the code is NOT making it to the function. Before GDB can get to the function, it crashes. So I can't print the parameters to test them.

Comment: @Ryan try to use empty params array. remove all append's

Comment: @MickMacCallum can you please explain what you mean? I am not familiar with final or private. I am using a View Controller and inside the view controller is an action button

Comment: @Ryan As in `@objc func sendMessage(sender: NSTimer) { // ... }`.

Comment: Can you confirm the class name of your View Controller is indeed importTextMessage? FWIW, it's LLDB, not GDB. Very different. You might put this next to your timer setup code and include the output in your question: `print("Class: \(self.dynamicType) Address: \(unsafeAddressOf(self))")` to make sure there's no mistake there.

Comment: @MickMacCallum - I changed it to '@'objc func sendMessage(sender: NSTimer){ and i am still getting the error, and it is not making it to sendMessage.

Comment: You know what? `sendMessage` sounds awfully generic and is probably colliding with a reserved name in the Objective-C runtime. Name it something that would never be used at a system level, like `ryansFavoriteTargetMethod`

Comment: @BaseZen , importTextMessage comes from another VC :  let importTextMessage = TextMessageTableViewController()

Comment: @BaseZen , When i run the function right before the NSTimer, like so : importTextMessage.sendMessage(params) , it works perfectly and I receive the message on my phone no hastle, so i don't think it is the name

Comment: That's your problem. I've updated my answer. Stylistically, avoid extremely generic callback function names, as I've advised, even though it's not the issue.

Comment: @BaseZen if I understand you correctly, you are saying that the Timer loses the context of importTextMessage at some point, and needs an actual reference to the view controller? As in TextMessageTableViewController.sendMessage?

Comment: Nothing happens "at some point" (during runtime). It's just a matter of syntax rules when writing your code. See my example below and if that sorts it out. It's not an "actual reference to the view controller". You're just following the rules of naming a function. When a function is a member of a class, you simply say: `ClassName.functionName` to name it as a selector.

Comment: `self` is the actual reference to the view controller that the `NSTimer` holds onto, and you're doing that part correctly already.